# Convexity and non-convexity of a function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The following inequality constraint function is nonconvex
\begin{equation}
\frac{G_{ii}P_i}{\sum_{j=1,i \neq j} G_{ij} P_j + \sigma_i^2} \geq \gamma_0
\end{equation}

However, by applying function transformation, the constraint can be written as
\begin{equation}
-G_{ii}P_i + \gamma_0 \sum_{j=1,i \neq j} G_{ij} P_j + \gamma_0 \sigma_i^2 \leq 0
\end{equation}
which is obviously a convex constraint in $p_i$ (more specifically an LP)

I am wondering why they are different? They are same equation, but one is non-convex and the other is convex.

Comment: If $P_i$ are your variables then both constraints describe the same convex *set* (assuming appropriate nonnegativity for the denominator). The *function* whose hypograph appears in the first constraint is concave (on appropriate domain). No contradiction anywhere.

Comment: Similarly, $x/(y+1) = 1$ is a nonlinear constraint, $x=y+1$ is a linear constraint, but they describe the same feasible set.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 well, except for the point $y=-1$... So more accurately, the constraint pair $x/(y+1)=1$, $y>-1$ is equivalent to the constraint pair $x=y+1$, $y>=-1$

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes, sorry -- I was assuming $x,y\ge 0$ but I didn't say that.